# Conservar firma digital en pdf

Tags: c#, pdf

Estoy realizando un aplicacion de consola que descarga varios archivos .pdf de un servicio web de nuestra misma organizacion, para luego realizar un merge y con calibre convertirlo a .epub.

El problema surge que estos documentos tienen una firma digital, cuando se realiza el merge desaparece y necesito que sigan conservando dicha firma en el pie de pagina, entiendo que al sufrir una pequeña modificacion es normal que desaparezca, entonces probe descargarlo y manualmente hacer una impresion desde windows en la impresora MIcrosoft to print pdf, imprimi varios y luego realice el merge y de este modo conservo la firma digital, el problema surge que al imprimir desde la aplicacion el archivo de salida queda en blanco.

Este es el codigo que utilizo para intentar imprimir el pdf

```
 PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
 ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(file);
 info.Verb = "Print";
 pd.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
 pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF";
 pd.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
 pd.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = Path.Combine(@"C:\Print\Salida" + ".pdf");
 pd.Print();
 info.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "firma digital"? La firma digital se usa para comprobar la identidad de la persona que ha firmado el documento, y por su naturaleza *es imposible conservarla si hay el más mínimo cambio en el documento*. Otra cosa que haya un texto de pie de página, pero eso no es una firma digital.

Comment: Por eso es que queria primero imprimir el documento en microsoft print to pdf que me conserva la firma y luego hacer el merge ya lo probe manualmente y funciona el problema que con el codigo de arriba me imprime la hoja en blanco